# Find where iOS is crashing based on crash reports

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

I have an app in beta using `TestFlight` and I have been noticing crash reports appearing.

most of the reports are this

[image]

If I click on the button `Open in project` in the `Organizer` it takes me no where

This appears to be an internal crash correct?

How can I find out what `UIBarButtonItem` is causing the crash?

Comment: I think your crash report is not symbolicate properly, else you should see the error in the thread 0 or 1, in general case when you open crash in Xcode from which you have uploaded build it will automatically symbolicate the crash

Comment: @Pyro How would I know if it was `symbolicated` properly and/or how can I get them to be that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Hope this will help you: [Apple doc Crash Report](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) , as you can see in the doc in the **Listing 4** the crash report is fully symbolicated , **Listing 6** shows partially symbolicated crash reports which looks like your case

From Apple Doc

> You must keep both the application binary and the .dSYM file in order to be able to fully symbolicate crash reports. You should archive these files for every build that you submit to iTunes Connect. The .dSYM and application binary are specifically tied together on a per-build-basis, and subsequent builds, even from the same source files, will not interoperate with files from other builds. If you use Xcode's Build and Archive command then they will be placed in a suitable location automatically. Otherwise any location searchable by Spotlight (such as your home directory) is fine.

For more information about this you can check portion after **Listing 6** in Symbolication

Answer (score 0):

you can use crashlytics for identifying where the app is crashed.It will give the Controller name and line number of code also.
https://docs.fabric.io/ios/index.html   [Document](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/index.html)

[Easy to add your project also](https://get.fabric.io/ios?locale=en-us)